# $\lim_{t\to\infty}a\sqrt{\log \log t}+bt$

Tags: limits

What is the reason for

$\lim_{t\to\infty}a\sqrt{\log \log t}+bt=\lim_{t\to \infty}bt\quad\quad  a,b\in \mathbb R$

How can I show this? de L'Hospital?

Comment: You want to exclude $b=0$, otherwise this is not true.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven: unless $a=0$ as well :-)

Comment: @YvesDaoust Indeed :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $b \neq 0$ you can argue as follows: L'Hopital's Rule shows that $\frac {\log \log t} {t^{2}} \to 0$. Now write $a\sqrt {\log \log t}+bt$ as $bt[1+ \frac  a b\sqrt {\frac {\log \log t} {t^{2}}}]$.

Comment: Sir, I think that it should also be assumed that $b\ne 0$?

Comment: @Koro You are right. Thanks.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I don't understand the conclusion. Are we using $\lim \big(bt\cdot[...]\big)=\lim bt\cdot \lim [...]$ here? I thought this not work in general if one of the factors in a product does not converge.

Comment: @user826130 If $f(t)=g(t)h(t)$ and $h(t) \to 1$ then $f(t)$ has a limit iff $g$ does and the limits are equal.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this limit also avoiding de l'Hospital. In particular you have only to use the hierarchy of infinities:
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}a\sqrt{\log{(\log{t})}}+bt=\lim_{t\to\infty}t\Big(\frac{a[\log({\log{t})}]^{1/2}}{t}+b\Big)$$
Now since the logarithm goes to infinity slower than $t$, or in general than $t^k$ (with $k$ positive) so it remains:
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}bt$$